# how to ajaxify the Wagtail-CMS page's actions?

Tags: wagtail

I need to let the admin users to stay in the page while they press any of (Publish, Unpublish, save_review ... etc), and not redirecting to any other pages nor refreshing the edit page, but instead, only apply the requested changes and get a notification(message) that has the action's status(succeeded or failed).

Notes:

1. I don't need the JQ code-Sample, but the backend (pythonic-way)functionality to control such event.
2. the reasons are many, for example to improve the UX and decrease the server/networking costs...etc.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to 'Ajaxify' the behaviour to achieve most of this goal, however I understand where you were heading.

When a Page is saved (either to publish, unpublish or even just save a draft) a POST request is made to the Django server which will save to the database and then redirect to the page's parent by default. Unfortunately to support this with a ajax style request would require a fair bit of work.

However, you can modify the redirect behaviour using the Wagail Hooks system, this allows you to write custom logic for core behaviour throughout your Wagtail code.

**Firstly - pleas read the introduction and overview of [Wagtail Hooks](https://docs.wagtail.io/en/stable/reference/hooks.html?highlight=after_edit_page#hooks)**

### Example

- Create a hook that will keep the user on the edit page when POSTed (Save draft, Publish, etc)
- In your `wagtail_hooks.py` file add the following

```py
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from django.urls import reverse

from wagtail.core import hooks


@hooks.register("after_edit_page")
def after_edit_page(request, page):

    if request.method == "POST":
        target_url = reverse("wagtailadmin_pages:edit", args=[page.id])
        return redirect(target_url)
```

- Note: You could look at not redirecting but you need to return a response as the Save button submits a POST.

Comment: If this is not sufficient, it might be worth adding a new question or revising this existing one to better convey the actual problem you are trying to resolve (ie. why dont you want the page to reload?).

Comment: there are many reasons, one is the UX, and the other is the server load, for example, imagine if there are 1000 editors at the same time, each time saving refreshing page will cost much more than just an http request to save change without downloading the entire page again, especially, most of the contents are not cached

Comment: Sounds like some great improvement ideas, especially the caching. If you ha e the time it would be really helpful to split those ideas up and raise them as feature requests at the Wagtail repo - https://github.com/wagtail/wagtail/issues - it might also be good to suggest some specific improvements to UX if you have ideas. It may not happen instantly but at least on GitHub it can be discussed and tracked and maybe someone will contribute the improvement. Hope that helps.